# Retrieve data from SQLite using xamarin Android & C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android

I have a class that gets longitude and latitude from user's device and and saves it to an SQLite database. Here's the code:

```
    [Activity(Label = "GetLocation")]
public class GetLocation : Activity, ILocationListener
{
    Button btncreate;
    EditText txtlong;
    EditText txtlat;

    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(GetLocation).Name;
    Location _currentLocation;
    LocationManager _locationManager;
    string _locationProvider;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GetLocation);
        txtlong = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtlong);
        txtlat = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtlat);
        btncreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnvalidate);
        btncreate.Click += Btncreate_Click;

        InitializeLocationManager();
    }

    void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager) GetSystemService(LocationService);
        Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
                                              {
                                                  Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
                                              };
        IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);
        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            _locationProvider = string.Empty;
        }
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Using " + _locationProvider + ".");
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }
    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }
    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras) { }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _currentLocation = location;
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            txtlong.Text = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
            txtlat.Text = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
        }
        else
        {
            txtlong.Text = _currentLocation.Longitude.ToString();
            txtlat.Text = _currentLocation.Latitude.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Btncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Location.db3");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
            db.CreateTable<DataTable>();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Longitude = txtlong.Text;
            tbl.Latitude = txtlat.Text;
            db.Insert(tbl);
            NextPage();
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Data Store Successfully...,", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
    void NextPage()
    {
        //code to get next page
    }

}
```

the DataTable class is as follows:

```
    class DataTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

once it has saved the data, I would like another class (activity) to be able to display it on a separate .axml page. my problem is I am a programmer in training (college) and have no clue what to do. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show your `DataTable`. Edit your questuion & put it. I am confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start a new activity using

```
StartActivity(typeof(Activity2));
```

and in the **OnCreate** of your `Activity2` set you new .axml layout:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyView);
}
```

Then to retrieve the data use **Query**:

```
string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Location.db3");
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
var dataTables = db.Query<DataTable>("select * from DataTable");
```

I'd recommend you to read [SQLite: GettingStarted](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/GettingStarted) and if you want to improve that move all about SQLite to another class to reuse the code of openning an `SQLiteConnection`. Also if you can use asynchronous calls in order to prevent blocking the UI while persisting data in your database.

Also check [Xamarin Android docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/) that is really helpful

HIH

Comment: Hello, Do I need to add something specific to the .axml file? because am getting a blank page when the activity loads

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to make the layout of your activity in your axml. If it's simple you can you use the help of the designer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/

Comment: It needed a `<ListView>` to display.